# Change html with javascript with a input form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I an php-html page, i want to change the position of an image dynamic with PHP, i know how to do that, but I also want to have a user preview before submit the values.
my code:

```
<form class="ysize" action="phpchangesize.php" method="get" name="zs"><span style="color:#FF0000"><strong>-<input name="chsize" size="1" type="text" value="400" />px <input name="sb" type="submit" value="Change Cover Top" /></strong></span></form>
<style>
.ysize
{
position:absolute;
right:0px;
top:0px;
}
.cover
{
position:absolute;
height:100%;
width:100%;
left:0px;
top:-400px;
z-index:-1;
}
</style>
<img class="cover" alt="" src="<?php echo $profilecover ?>" />
```

Now when the user press the submit button the php write the **400** value and will echo it in the page, now I dont want the user to reload the page for every try of the value, and i want to make a live preview with **javascript**, to see how will be before submit them.

So the JS have to **detect** the form value and change livethe **400** value on the **css style**, to see the user how will be the image with this position before submit.

Comment: Please add the JavaScript code your're working on to your question and the fiddle so that someone can help to improve it.

Comment: That fiddle is useless. You help by providing a working proof of concept, not by copy-pasting some code. What have you tried? `onkeydown`?

Comment: i dont know if this was correct from what i try, non of them work.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use Ajax to call your PHP script or the page will always reload when the users submits the form. Add an event listener for the `submit` event to the form. In this handler, do the Ajax call to your PHP script and update the `img` tag with the new attributes. Be sure to `return false;` or `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the form actually submitting and thus reloading the page. Good luck.